# Registros em propriedade de navegação ICollection<> não estão sendo gravados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou tentando fazer uma inclusão de itens em uma propriedade do tipo lista mas não estou conseguindo incluir os registros no banco.

Primeiramente tenho os seguintes modelos de classes:

```cs
public class Frota
{
    public Frota() {
        Veiculos = new List<Veiculos>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virutal ICollection<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }
}

public class Veiculo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }   
}
```

Mapeamento:

```cs
public class FrotaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Frota>
{
    ...
    HasMany(x => x.Veiculos)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("FrotaId");
            x.MapRightKey("VeiculoId");
            x.ToTable("FrotaVeiculos");
        });
}
```

Executo um processo em duas etapas onde, crio um Lote e em seguida adiciono os veículos:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include="...")] FrotaViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var frota = await Context.Frotas
            .Include(x => x.Veiculos)
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);

        foreach (var veiculo in frota.Veiculos)
            frota.Veiculos.Remove(veiculo);
        frota.Veiculos.Clear();

        foreach (var veiculo in model.Veiculos)
            frota.Veiculos.Add(veiculo);

        Context.Entry(frota).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = model.Id })
}
```

Mas os `Veiculos` não são adicionados no banco de dados e eu não consigo entender porque.

O que está faltando ou está errado nesse código?

Comment: Seu mapeamento está entre Frota - Veiculo. No seu código de exemplo, vc está ligando Lotes com veículos. Ou você esqueceu de colocar a classe Lote, ou tem algo errado mesmo.

Comment: Foi erro de digitação. E obrigado pelo aviso.

Comment: A sua collection de veículos dentre de FrotaViewModel, é de qual tipo? Os veículos que você está adicionando, já existem na base?

Comment: São do mesmo tipo sim, `ICollection<Veiculo>`. Não há registro na base nesse momento que estou testando. Da `Frota` sim, mas dos veículos não!

Comment: @jpgrassi, Aliás, na tabela `Veiculos` existe também, só não consigo gravar na tabela de relacionamento `FrotaVeiculos`.

Comment: Já tentei obter os registros de `Veiculo` do banco também para inserir na propriedade `Veiculos` de `Frota` mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Resolvi fazendo `Context.Frotas.Attach(frota);` após o `SingleOrDefault`. E olha que não tem nenhum configuração extra para o Contexto além de `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` e `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`.

Comment: Acredito que você também não precise daquele mapping com Veiculos. A tabela FrotaVeiculos é criada automaticamente, a não ser que você tenha outros campos personalizados nela. Caso não, pode tirar e faz o teste.